# How to move local directories to Alibaba Cloud OSS using ossutil tool?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I want to move a local directory to Alibaba Cloud OSS bucket using `ossutil` tool.

The command I used to upload the video directory to OSS bucket - testbucket is `ossutil cp -r video oss://testbucket` but it throws no such keyword error.

Comment: I've never used this tool, but after a quick google, the answers I found all use a different order for the arguments. They use `ossutil cp video oss://testbucket -r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
ossutil cp -r video/ oss://bucket testbucket

Refer: https://help.aliyun.com/document_detail/50452.html?spm=a2c4g.11186623.3.3.1e5751a1SrXLBo

Answer (score 1):

**Be aware of that [/] in the end of source dir.**
Try this:

```
ossutil cp -r folder_name/ oss://bucket-name
```

Refer:
https://github.com/aliyun/ossutil/issues/45#issuecomment-448818209

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Note: -r has to be at the end.

```
aliyun oss cp folder_name/ oss://bucket-name -r
```